# Show Featured products with custom taxonomy template

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, loop, taxonomy

I have a custom taxonomy template / archive called taxonomy-brand.php and this loops fine and shows the products that have the same "brand" taxonomy, trouble is I want to have a second loop in the same template that only shows products that belong to this "brand" taxonomy but also are featured.... I cant get it to work, I can only figure out how to show all featured but it doesnt filter out for the specific brand

Comment: Usually helps if you include your code and maybe someone can tell you why it's ignoring the brand taxonomy.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.